# Monitor file after cut and paste (Windows Shell Extension?)

Tags: c++, windows, file, copy, shell-extensions

I'm currently in the idea phase for a small application that requires keeping track of specific, user chosen files.

I want the system to be intuitive, such that a user can change the file name, directory name, or move the file to a new location, and the application would still be able to keep track of the file.

Now, I know that I can monitor directories already, for the majority of these kinds of changes, with windows system calls.

The problem I'd have is finding if/when a file is cut, copied, or pasted somewhere.  I've read a little about shell extensions, but they have actually rather confused me (since I haven't had the time to actually read good and long about them yet).  Is there a way I could monitor a file for being cut/pasted/copied, so that my application could continue to track the file in it's new location?  Would I have to do this through a shell extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use shortcut objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/24/10133280.aspx) to track files even if they are renamed or moved.